# How do I bind Ext JS controls with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs

I'm starting a new project with ASP.NET MVC, and I have to use ExtJS as the widgets library (we're not going to do MVC in the client) because the company already has a license for it.

We have a bad experience binding ExtJS to the HTML generated by MVC from a previous project. What we usually did was make the MVC `<input>`s etc. hidden, generate ExtJS controls based on their attributes, and sync the two's values. It's difficult to maintain, and it looks ugly in code.

What I would want to have is that ExtJS controls will get their values directly from the HTML generated by ASP.NET, and be able to submit them to the controller in a way MVC will understand and be able to deserialize to a model object.

I would also prefer using jQuery validation, which is integrated with ASP.NET MVC, and not ExtJS validations. Is that possible with ExtJS controls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since no one answered, I'll outline what I ended up doing.

1. on each input, add a data-ext-type attribute which marks what kind of ExtJS control to convert it to.
2. using jQuery, find all inputs in a form
3. for each input:

   1. `var container = $(input).replaceWith("<div style='display: inline;'></div>");`
   2. create the ExtJS control based on the data-ext-type, setting it's value to the input.value, it's inputId to the input.id, its name to input.name. you can also convert other properties of the source input to ExtJS config items. in particular, you would have to copy all the data-val-* attributes MVC generates to the `inputAttrTpl` config of ExtJS, by looping over the input.attributes array.
   3. render the control to the `containter` you created in step 1 of the loop, using the `renderTo` config or the `.render()` function.

The ComboBox has its own challenges, because its actual value to be validated is in a hidden field just above the visible input. the same goes for the Html Editor, but we don't use one.